# How to Parse this JSON String in android studio using java

Tags: java, android, json, database, parsing

This is the error i'm getting!

```
exception caught:
    org.json.JSONException: Value com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RealResponseBody@42b1af18 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class Main_Activity extends Activity {
    public static final String TAG = Main_Activity.class.getSimpleName();

    private CurrentWeather mCurrentWeather;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_);

        double latitude = 37.8267;
        double longitude = -122.423;
        String apiKey = "26351d54df6d07aff2086c471da36d36";
        String forecastURL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey + "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;



        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(forecastURL)
            .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    String jsonData = response.body().toString();
                    Log.e(TAG, jsonData);
                    try {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            mCurrentWeather = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.e(TAG, "exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.network_isUnavailable), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Main_Activity is running!");
    }

    private CurrentWeather getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException  {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("{timezone}");
        Log.i(TAG, "From json: " + timezone);

        return new CurrentWeather();
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        Boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment mDialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        mDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your json may be corrupted. Can provide a json example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything seems to be fine. Except in the below line

```
String jsonData = response.body().toString();
```

Replace the above line with the following

```
 String jsonData = response.body().string();
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! that fixed it!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you upvote and accept the answer so that anyone else who faces the same issue can resolve it quickly?